# Android. Кодирование видео в H.264

Tags: android, видео, android-camera

Необходимо брать данные с камеры смартфона и кодировать в H.264

Если,допустим, можем взять байты в методе

`public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera)`

То какие следующие действия ? Как-то передать MediaCodec-ку в отдельном потоке ?
Спасибо.

На выходе хочу получать `byte[]` уже в закодированном виде.

Comment: не хотелось бы залезать в ffmpeg для этого случая

Comment: к сожалению, нет времени искать решение для вас, но вот вроде бу правильный запрос в гугл https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20camera%20record%20h264

Comment: @metalurgus. ну решения не прошу, прошу лишь совета. В гугле много информации изучил. в том числе пример гугловский `grafika`, но там они записывают в память телефона,также использовав MediaMuxer родной